# "ionic cordova run ios" don't work

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I never saw what should happen after I run that command, but maby there should be added app in my Iphone. after line "ionic cordova run ios" nothing happens , the all log :

```
cordova run ios
Running app-scripts build: --platform ios --target c
ordova
[21:10:23]  build dev started ...
[21:10:23]  clean started ...
[21:10:23]  clean finished in 20 ms
[21:10:23]  copy started ...
[21:10:23]  deeplinks started ...
[21:10:23]  deeplinks finished in 68 ms
[21:10:23]  transpile started ...
[21:10:29]  transpile finished in 5.71 s
[21:10:29]  preprocess started ...
[21:10:29]  preprocess finished in 2 ms
[21:10:29]  webpack started ...
[21:10:29]  copy finished in 6.05 s
[21:10:39]  webpack finished in 10.18 s
[21:10:39]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong s
ource map and will not find Browserslist config. Set
 it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent th
is warning.
[21:10:41]  sass finished in 1.51 s
[21:10:41]  postprocess started ...
[21:10:41]  postprocess finished in 21 ms
[21:10:41]  lint started ...
[21:10:41]  build dev finished in 17.66 s
> cordova run ios
(node:3192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhand
led promise rejection (rejection id: 1): xcodebuild
was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or great
er from App Store
(node:3192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, pr
omise rejections that are not handled will terminate
 the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from y
our app with --livereload?

[21:10:46]  lint finished in 5.38 s
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install [XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) in order to build an Ionic app for iOS.

See the [cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/) for additional information.

Comment: So i need to download Xcode from appstore on my Iphone, configure it and then that command will work from my Windows OS , Webstorm terminal ?

Comment: And as I saw in a lot of stackoverflow answers that there is no way to emulate via cordova ios on windows for free. Thats right ?

Comment: No, that won't solve your problem. You can't build an iOS app on a Windows machine. The only possibility is, as far as I know, building it via the cloud. Have a look at this post by Josh Morony: https://www.joshmorony.com/building-ionic-2-applications-for-ios-without-a-mac/